# Can I break a box in Deus Ex without a melee weapon?

Tags: deus-ex

I only have weapons that cost ammo. I would like to break a box open. I would not like to use any ammo.

Is there any way to break a box open without a melee weapon?

Comment: It's been too long since I played last, but I think you can't use bare fists (although, did you try using the hotkey of an empty slot?), so your best bet is [cheating](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_console_commands) for a crowbar...

Comment: I believe I remember crates taking fall damage from a few stories up in Hell's Kitchen. Though I can't spin the game up right now to test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently did a "challenge run" of Deus Ex where I only permitted myself to use rifle weapons (sniper rifle, assault rifle, shotguns.)

That meant I needed to find ways to open crates without shooting them or using melee weapons. Here are the ways I found:

1. Drop the box from a height.
2. Stand on top of something and throw the crate upwards. You only need to stand on something about waist-height, like another crate, for this to work. Staircases are also good for this.
3. Set the crate on fire. A lot of locations have flaming barrels that work well for this. Try to get the box on top of the fire so the fire burns the crate completely. You could also use flares to set the crate on fire.
4. If you have the Run Speed augmentation, turn that on and do high-jumps on top of the box - the box will break after you land on it one or two times.
5. Put the box in a doorway and close the door.
6. Find a box of TNT and throw it at the crate you want to open.

Note that the only ways to break crates underwater are using melee weapons or the mini-crossbow, so if you don't have a melee weapon or a crossbow then it is impossible to break crates under water.

Answer (score 9):

The boxes take damage if you **jump on** them from some height or **drop** them (dropping would be preferred, because that way you cannot accidentally take damage). Height of ~2 meters is usually enough.

Answer (score 4):

I did a heavy-weapons run where I didn't have inventory room for a melee weapon.
My typical solution was to toss the box up, jump, catch the box and toss it up again.
Requires some practice and some head room, but one jump and toss gets enough height to break a supply crate.

Answer (score 1):

The original Deus Ex (and the follow up Invisible War) does not allow you to attack with fists. There are a couple of solutions to this but the most obvious one would be to use a melee weapon such as a crowbar or blade (Dragon Tooth Energy Blade anybody?)

If you don't have one currently you'll either need to search around to find one or cheat. As [pointed out by Zommuter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81968/can-i-break-a-box-in-deus-ex-without-a-melee-weapon#comment113527_81968) there is a detailed article on [enabling and using cheats in Deus Ex here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_console_commands) which will help you with a melee weapon if you do not wish to hunt around for one (which is not always an option).

The other option is installing a mod to enable fists, although I am unaware of one that adds fists without changing other parts of the game - for example [The Nameless Mod](http://thenamelessmod.com/wiki/The_Nameless_Mod) adds 'fists' in replacement for the 'swimming' skill but also changes the story line.